# Status of world during first time lord came to create souls?

Tags: atma, caste-system, creation

If souls are situated in material bodies(Bhramana,Kstriya,Vasiya,Sudra,Animals,Rakshas,Asuras,etc) ,then in the beginning of the universe the souls will have their first birth and will have no karma effects and in that situation on which basis four castes and souls on animal beings will put by god.As Veda's describes that these four castes were the initial stage of the universe.

Can anyone please clarify my doubts?

Comment: Soul is not created and is always eternal.. See answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/soul-creation-and-vedanta

Comment: Regarding "On what basis?" .. It is on the basis of previous life of that person.. There were previous Universes before present Universe.. and due to eternity of Samsara we can't trace origin of first creation.. It goes back and back in time... see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11660/do-hindus-believe-in-adam-and-eve-if-not-who-is-the-first-person-man-or-woman/11662#11662